How to Edit REG_EXPAND_SZ type
I am trying to edit an existing registry key from a .reg file. I want to change the vaue of the path below command is not updating registry key
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\c2wts]
"ImagePath"=REG_EXPAND_SZ:"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Identity Foundation\V3.5\c2wtshost.exe"

If you manually add a sample entry and export it you see that a .reg file holds it as a hex(2) entry. The characters are in unicode and a 16-bit 00,00 is used for termination:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.0

[HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\c2wts] 
"ImagePath"=hex(2):25,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,\
  6c,00,65,00,73,00,25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,\
  00,49,00,64,00,65,00,6e,00,74,00,69,00,74,00,79,00,20,00,46,00,6f,00,75,00,\
  6e,00,64,00,61,00,74,00,69,00,6f,00,6e,00,5c,00,56,00,33,00,2e,00,35,00,5c,\
  00,63,00,32,00,77,00,74,00,73,00,68,00,6f,00,73,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,00,00

Alternatively, you can use reg add to edit the entry:
reg add HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\c2wts /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%ProgramFiles^%\Windows Identity Foundation\V3.5\c2wtshost.exe /f


Hi i just add qutoation marks to the path how to do it , "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Identity Foundation\V3.5\c2wtshost.exe", now ImagePath has no qutoation marks , and i want to do it by command because i have lot of servers to do this

It's unusual to need quotation marks in the registry data. But if you do need them, have you tried double quotation marks ""%Program Files? If that doesn't work, sometimes tripling or escaping "\" quotations can do what you need.

is that my command is corrct [HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\c2wts] "ImagePath"=REG_EXPAND_SZ:""%ProgramFiles%\Windows Identity Foundation\V3.5\c2wtshost.exe""
